# How can I better/faster join thousands of cylinder objects in blender 3.4? the Join() operator is far too slow

Tags: python, blender

As in the title, I have thousands (up to 50-100k) of cylinders and spheres that I need to 'Join' into a single object. Using Join() is far too slow. I tried a lot of ideas using bmesh but nothing works, because operators that I used to use ( like bmesh.ops.join() ) , are no longer available in 3.4?

I can program in python no problem.
Any help, kind of desperately needed.
Thanks!

I tried using various bmesh. operators but the older ones are not available in 3.4.

I tried making a new object and merging but those operators seem to be gone now too.